# Android: How to set information from textView in other activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, textview

Here is what I want to do:

I created **class User** with following:

```
public class User {

private String name;
private String gender;
private int age;

public User() {
    super();
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [name=" + name + ", gender=" + gender + ", age=" + age
            + "]";
}
}
```

In Activity UserIntro user can enter name, age and gender and I want to set those values in User and then display it in other Activity. Latter I also want to store those informations in SQLite, but for now this is ok.

**UserInfoActivity** looks like this:

```
public class UserIntroActivity extends Activity {

public boolean started;
EditText userName;
ImageButton girl;
ImageButton boy;
EditText age;
String pol;
String name;
int userAge;

User user = new User();

public boolean isStarted() {
    return started;
}

public void setStarted(boolean started) {
    this.started = started;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_intro);

    girl = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonGirl);
    boy = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonBoy);
    age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAge);

    Button btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);

    girl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pol = "zensko";
            user.setGender(pol);

        }
    });

    boy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pol = "musko";

        }

    });

    btnGo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);

            Intent intent = new Intent(UserIntroActivity.this,
                    EnterActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            name = userName.getText().toString();
            userAge = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
            user.setName(name);
            user.setAge(userAge);

            Log.d("USER", name + " , " + userAge + " , " + pol);

            finish();
        }
    });
    }
}
```

In **EnterActivity** I ant to show name, a and gender.

```
public class EnterActivity extends Activity {
User user = new User();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter);


    TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    test.setText("ime: " + user.toString());

}
```

}

But when I do like this result is null, 0, null so I see that user.set...() did not set values. Does anyone have idea why and how to fin the problem? Thank you all!

Comment: In your EnterActivity you declare `User user = new User();` and then try to do `user.toString()` on a new User that has no variables in itialized. You need a way to pass the user from your first activity to the second, as @marshallino16 suggests.

Comment: Not to sound rude but, you really need to go through some simple Java tutorials if you don't understand why you aren't getting the value set in your second class.

Comment: @codeMagic I will do that :) I am still new, so some basic things are not absolutely clear but here I am learning too :D

Comment: That's good that you are learning but you really need to know basic OOP and Java before tackling Android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Google can tell you with a small search.**

```
Intent intent= new Intent(this,EnterActivity .class);
intent.putExtra("txt", txtview.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

And then to retrieve your text :

```
String receive = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("txt");
```